# Error delivering messages My own PHP Chat

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, i'm working in a chat, but only the user who sent the message, can see it. the other one cant, example:

Logged in as David:
(cant upload photos)
-ME: Hello
-ME: Lalalala

Logged in as Shinny:
-ME: Hihihi

it is supposed that what shinny writed should be displaying in my chat, and what im writing should display on shinny's chat, but the incoming message is not showing
How it should be
-ME: Hello
-Shinny: Hihihi
-ME: Lalalala

Here is the code: What can i do to solve this thing?

```
 <?php 

    $chaquery = "SELECT u.*,c.* FROM chats c 
     INNER JOIN users u WHERE u.user_id = c.chat_from 
     AND chat_from = '".$session['user_id']."' 
     AND chat_to = '".$_GET['id']."'
```

(id of the destiny user)

```
     OR u.user_id = c.chat_to AND u.user_id = c.chat_from
     AND chat_to = '".$session['user_id']."'
     AND chat_from = '".$_GET['id']."'
```

(id of the destiny user AGAIN)

```
ORDER BY chat_id ";
          $chares = mysql_query($chaquery);

            if($chares)
            {
                while($chafilas = mysql_fetch_assoc($chares))
                {
                    $me = $chafilas["chat_remit"];
                    $message = $chafilas["chat_cont"];
                    $hour = $chafilas["chat_hora"];
                    $date = $chafilas["chat_fecha"];
                    $day = $chafilas["chat_dia"];
                    $fullname = $chafilas["usuario_nombre"];
                    $nick = $chafilas["usuario_nick"];
                    $userphoto = $chafilas["usuario_foto"];

                    if($me){?><div class="panel-body">
                     <img src="avatar/<?php echo $tufoto;?>" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" width="55px" class="ui"/>
                     <a href="<?php echo $xnick;?>"><b style="font-size:16px;"><?php echo $xnombre;?></b></a><br><?php echo $xmensaje;?>
                    </div><?php }}}?>
```

Here THE TABLE

```
  `chat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chat_from` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `chat_to` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `chat_message` longtext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `chat_hour` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `chat_day` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `chat_date` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `chat_seen` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`chat_id`)
```

Comment: You have to consider looking at this `OR u.user_id = c.chat_to` closelly on your query. An `OR` statement without parentesis is a crime.

Comment: are you using ajax?where is ajax?

Comment: possible repost of [Creating a chat in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026599/creating-a-chat-in-php-need-help-users-dont-get-their-messages) (don't do that here, instead keep editing). Your question is more understandle now, but still missing your debugging details; the variable states (usernames are not sufficient) and an excerpt of relevant database contents.

Comment: can you explain better that AN OR STATEMENT without parentesis is a crime, i dont know too much about mysql

Comment: mario, i dont know how to present you the database contents

Comment: That is not about just SQL that is about logic. If you have this expression ( A and B or C ) this should evaluate to this answers: If C is true A and/or B doesnt matter the whole expression will be true. So every time you put an `OR` statement in a query you have to consider the logic.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your code..are you saving these chat content somewhere?? if yes you have to refresh that particular div which contain your chat msgs using ajax call something like this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
//populating chat the first time
refresh_chat();
// recurring refresh every 1 seconds
setInterval("refresh_chat()", 1000);

    $("#send").click(function() {
        // getting the values that user typed
        var send    = $("#send").val();
        var chat    = $("#chat").val();
        var data   = 'add='+ add + '&comp='+ comp;

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chat.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ 
            // this happen after we get result
                $("#scroll").fadeOut(500, function(){
                    $(this).html(html).fadeIn(500);
                    $("#scroll").val("");
                    //alert('hello');

                        });


            });   
             return false;
            }
function refresh_shoutbox() {
    var data = 'refresh=1';
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chat.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
            $("#chat").html(html);
        }
    });

    });


});
</script>
```

hope this helps u :)

Comment: thanks with that, it really helps, and Yes, i'm sending it to a table, but the saving is working, now i'm working on an SQL script to give me the different user messages, but when i call the script it ends the other user message but my name, or the opposite, now i think i need to separate the queries for every user

Comment: @davco98 no need to create separate query for diff user, try using while or foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION`, you can do 2 queries to get the results you want

```
SELECT * FROM (
  // Get messages to
  SELECT u1.* ,c1.* FROM chats c1
  INNER JOIN users u1
  ON u1.user_id = '".$session['user_id']."' 
  AND c1.chat_to = '".$session['user_id']."'
  AND c1.chat_from = '".$_GET['id']."' 

  UNION

  // Get messages from user  
  SELECT u2.* ,c2.* FROM chats c2
  INNER JOIN users u2
  ON u2.user_id = '".$_GET['id']."'
  AND c2.chat_to = '".$_GET['id']."'
  AND c2.chat_from = '".$session['user_id']."' 

) result
ORDER BY chat_id
```

SQLFiddle Example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d2af7/29

---

Note,
(1) you are open to sql injection by using `$_GET` values directly in your query, and
(2) from the `mysql_` doc - This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.